# Determine if any 2D polygon (including convex or concave polygons) intersects with AABB bounding

Tags: c#, math, game-physics, computational-geometry, intersection

I'm developing a 2D program that requires a lot of judgment on whether a polygon (generated or imported by the user, could be either convex or concave) is intersecting (overlaping) with AABBs. The data structure part I've implemented with kdtree, and I now need a way to determine whether a polygon intersects with an AABB box.

I have seen many discussions on the web, but they are all about convex polygons, and I have also seen methods that use each line segment of a polygon to determine if it intersects with an AABB, but since it is an AABB box, I am afraid this method is too expensive.

1 The polygon is defined by a series of Vector2 list stored in counterclockwise order, AABB Box is defined by List[minx,miny,maxx,maxy].

2 I only care whether they intersect or not, I don't need to return overlaping ranges or intersection points.

3 Any pre-processing of polygons is possible.

4 The language used is C#, and any available libraries are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to convert any polygon into triangles, this is called [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation). Then you can use any triangle/aabb intersection algorithm you want.

In addition to this, you can draw an aabb around the polygon and check that against the other aabb first. If those don't intersect you don't have to check all the triangles separately.

Furthermore, you can use a bounding volume hierarchy to prevent doing unnecessary collision checks of the triangles and aabb. [This](https://jacco.ompf2.com/2022/04/13/how-to-build-a-bvh-part-1-basics/) is a nice explanation and implementation but it's in the context of raytracing. You can easily adapt it for your purposes though.

Comment: Thank you very much. But some of the polygons that are divided into triangles may be many, for example the user input polygon may look like a "circle plus a tail". Is it possible to decompose concave polygons into a minimum number of convex polygons, and is there a faster collision detection algorithm for convex polygons with AABB.

Comment: I think the amount of triangles generated scales linearly with the amount of vertices of your polygon, so compared to checking each line fo the polygon it doesn't get that much more expensive.

Comment: For convex polygons you can use the separating axis theorem, but this does not work for non-convex polygons. https://dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution, and compare with the performance of:  minimum convex polygons use GJK.